# Connect android emulator to the host LAN network

Tags: java, android, sockets, ioexception

I am writing an android app that connects to a server socket and get some data. The server resides in the same network as my host PC. I'm able to access the server running in my host PC using the android emulator with 10.0.2.2 ip address but I'm not able to access the server running in other PCs.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this? I'm able to access the server from my host PC.

Comment: You don't have to do anything special. Just use the right ip address.

Comment: I didn't tried, but how about using proxy? 1. run proxy on your host pc (ex.charles proxy) . 2. set port forwarding on proxy. 3. request on specific port.

Comment: @Helper..Thanks but I tried using the ip address.. It didnt work. and I'm not getting any replies also when I ping'ed the ip from the Terminal emulator.(Dev tools -> Terminal emulator)

Comment: You must have errors or exceptions. Which ones? Where does your code stick? If you use the app on a device; can it reach the server?

Comment: do check your firewall have block the connection from other PC ?